# Rails, validate social network users id

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

My users has fields where they will store user_ids from their social networks like VK, Facebook or Google+.

If someone sends me id of facebook something like 8978978979, how I will know that it is exactly user of facebook? Do I need to use api for each social network to determine it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Do I need to use api for each social network to determine it

If you mean you want to check if the `id` you've received is indeed corresponding to that of a social network, you'll be best using the `API`'s for each service, yes.

You'd be best doing it with a `before_create` callback, although calling an external API synchronously might cause problems if there is *any* lag:

```
#app/models/user.rb
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
   before_create :check_user

   private

   def check_user
      #check apis
   end
end
```

Of course, without any code/implementation, I cannot tell you specifically what you need. The above is where I'd start, but you'd have to add a lot of configuration to get it working.

Comment: So when validation is failed, I will just throw ValidationError?

Comment: It depends on which API you're using - if the API requires validation, then you'd have to validate against it. Again, if you provide code etc, I'll be in a much better position to advise!

Answer (score 0):

The thing is based on only `Id` you could not determine whether particular user belongs to which until unless you haven't store the provider as well.

In case of Auth Hash Of **`Facebook`** or **`Google+`**  Or you could take any other social media .

You have to store

**1:**  `provider => 'provider_name'` and

**2:**  `uid => 'uid_for_user'`

Hope I answer your question !!!